# search in fragment from navdrawer

Tags: java, android, fragment, navigation-drawer, searchbar

Hi I want to put a search bar into my navigation drawer which I want to filter the items from Fragment.

[image: Here is the screenshot.]

I have Fragement under the nav drawer in the ss. 
here is a bit of code.

```
  <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        />
```

Menu in the MainActivity

```
   if (id == R.id.action_search) {
       final MenuItem searchItem = item.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView)
          MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item); 

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
         }
```

here is the some chunk of code I got for search

```
        @Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    newText = newText.toLowerCase();
    List<Example> newlist = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Example example: newlist){
        String name = example.getTitle().getRendered().toLowerCase();
        if (name.contains(newText)) newlist.add(example);
    }
    adapter.setFilter(newlist);
    return true;
}
    }
```

Now how will I code the nav drawer in mainActivity or in fragment to make it possible that I can search in the fragment from nav drawer. Thanks.

Comment: You want to search the fragments from search in navigation drawer?

Comment: I want to search the item in fragment from nav drawer's search.

Answer (score 0):

Make a SearchManager class which fetches your data everytime onQueryTextChange is called.  Then make a custom listener in SearchManager and implement it in your fragment and refresh it everytime your listener is called.

I got something like this in my MainActivity

```
SearchManager searchManager = SearchManager.sharedInstance();

searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                        searchManager.onSearchQueryChanged(query);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                        searchManager.onSearchQueryChanged(query);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

SearchManager class, I use a singleton because I want only one instance I can access from both the activity and the fragment

```
 public class SearchManager {

        private static SearchManager searchManager;
        private OnSearchResultsListener onSearchResultsListener;
        private List<mObject> searchResultList = new ArrayList<>();

        public SearchManager() {
        }

        public void setOnSearchResultsListener(OnSearchResultsListener onSearchResultsListener) {
            this.onSearchResultsListener = onSearchResultsListener;
        }

        public static SearchManager sharedInstance() {
            if (searchManager == null) {
                searchManager = new SearchManager();
            }
            return searchManager;
        }

        public void onContactSearchQueryChanged(String query) {
//do your logic here
            this.searchResultList = ...;
            onContactsSearchResultsListener.OnSearchResults(searchResultList);
        }
    }
```

A simple custom listener

```
public interface OnSearchResultsListener {

    void OnSearchResults(List<mObject> searchResultList);

}
```

and then in your fragment

```
public class MFragment extends Fragment implements OnSearchResultsListener {
...
//in your OnCreateView
SearchManager.sharedInstance().setOnSearchResultsListener(this);
...
 @Override
    public void OnContactsSearchResults(List<mObject> searchResultList) {
     //refresh UI
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Gregory Nowik. Let me try this.